# NDsolve with endogenous boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I would like to solve a differential equation with a boundary that is implicitly determined by another equation (second equation in the NDsolve command below). The boundary is at s=S and determined by the equation that RC[S]==RA (where RA is a constant). Unfortunately, I cannot get the following code to work:

```
    \[Alpha]h = 0.2;
\[Alpha]z = 0.2; 
\[Gamma] = 1;
ph = 2;
pf = 1;
tC = 0;
TC = 0;
Tw = 0;
FC = 0.3;
G = 0;
w = 1;
\[Rho] = 0.2;
\[Sigma] = 1/(1 - \[Rho]);
L = 1;
R0 = 1;
RA = 0.5;

NDSolve[{RC'[s] == (\[Sigma] (ph + RC[s])^((\[Rho] + \[Sigma])/\[Sigma])\((\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (ph +RC[s])^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma]))) (((pf + tC) (-R0 + L (FC - G + s (pf + tC) + TC + Tw - w)))/L + (\[Gamma] (ph + RC[s])^\[Sigma] \((\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (ph + RC[s])^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])))^(2 - 1/\[Rho]))/\[Alpha]h))/((FC - G - R0/L + s (pf + tC) + TC + Tw - w)^2 (1 - \[Rho])), RC[S] == RA},RC[s], {s, 0, 10}, {S, 0, 10000}]
```

It produces the following error message:

```
NDSolve: The arguments should be ordered consistently.
```

I have tried other codes as well but haven't managed to get a solution. Help would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure whether I specify the boundary condition in the right way, and answers to similar questions on boundary conditions that I browsed through haven't helped either.

Thanks,

Wolfgang

Comment: For `NDSolve` all constants have to be defined numerically.  Also, you have `RC` as a function of s, but you are varying `S` as well.  After setting values for all your constants, you could possibly make a Table of solutions with varying S values, but for 10000 of them that may take awhile assuming the problem can be solved at all.

Comment: Weclome Wolfgang. With out the constants like `FC`, `RA`, etc.. we can not solve the problem. You'd need to specify everything such that people here can potentially solve the problem. Use the 'edit' button for that under your question.

Comment: Hi user21 and Bill Watts, sorry for that. I added the parameters and some more explanation on what the boundary condition is.

Comment: @WolfgangH. There is no definitive solution. Are you sure that there are no errors when writing equations and in the input data?

Comment: @AlexTrounev: I am pretty sure there must be a solution to it, as it seems to be a fairly standard problem in urban economics.

Comment: @WolfgangH. Just check the data and equation. I do not find the only solution. There are many solutions, so the question.

Comment: The role is `S` is unclear to me.  For instance, `{S, 0, 10000}` tells `NDSolve` to integrate over `S` from `0` to `10000`, but there is no derivative with respect to `S` in the equations.  Please explain.